# "Cut into" or "dig into"

Tags: word-choice

I have a question about the expression you can use to describe something pressing into something else.

Someone is walking an excited dog that wants to go in a different direction from where its owner is going, and its collar is pressing hard into its neck, possibly leaving a mark. When you are describing this situation, which sentence can you say?

> The collar is **cutting into** the dog's neck.
>
> The collar is **digging into** the dog's neck.

I am not sure which is the appropriate expression to describe this, "cut into" or "dig into."

Comment: Both are possible and appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say both, as Kate said.

I'd say "The collar is digging into the dog's neck". This is probably because I've heard it more. "Cutting into" kind of sounds like the dog is receiving pain.

But again, both sound pretty reasonable.